# hosting WordPress on Docker or on Physical host

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx, docker

I am planning to create a shared WordPress hosting system for clients.

The needed services are : PHP, MySQL/MariaDB, SFTP, (Nginx/Apache : which one is better and faster and more secure ? )

- If i am going to use Docker then the applications are going to be
  mounted on a volume on the Docker host the container will include the
  PHP files.
- If on a physical CentOS or Ubuntu host then all the websites will
  share the same PHP files.

The Nginx/Apache will be one for all the websites, and one database engine to serve them all.

Have anyone done such scenario?
what do you suggest, what are the advantages and disadvantages in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

To minimize your involvement while installation and management of WordPress for your customers, better choose already packaged clusters based on Docker containers. [Here is a recent article](https://blog.jelastic.com/2017/12/14/wordpress-cluster-automatic-scaling-cloud-hosting-in-containers/) with details and instruction how to install them from Jelastic marketplace.

Each package includes:

- NGINX load balancer
- two NGINX PHP servers that are automatically scaled
- replicated master-master MySQL databases
- storage node

Scaling, replication and the whole cluster installation are fully automated, so you save lots of time and get a production-ready solution.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx with Fastcgi is more secure and fast. You can limit max request/ip after the connection will throttled. For database use mariadb. For caching the whole wordpress site use memcached. It will load your whole site in ram and reduce server load. Best for static wordpress site as well as dynamic.